# Getting info from numbers in a string in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a big list called data. Each element contains a big string with 32 integers/floats that I want to extract. For example [Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9199101) are the second, third and fourth elements of data (these are strings). I can remove the leading whitespace at the beginning using

```
for item in data:
    item = item.strip()
```

However I'm dumbfounded after that. Here's my attempt on the first element, which is a string of numbers from 1 to 32 (looks something like [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9199141)):

```
chans = data[0]
chans = chans.strip()
labels = [] # preload


for i in range(len(chans)):
if chans[i]==" ":
    continue
else:
    if chans[i]!=" ":
        labels.append(chans[i:i+1])
    else:
        labels.append(chans[i])
```

However this gives me an "out of range" error, which I don't know why. if I reduce the range to be len(chans)-1, then the output looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9199200). How can I fix this?

Comment: can you not just `labels = chans.strip().split()`?

Comment: @cmd Wow I've been stuck on this for a whole day and you just saved my life hahahaha thank you very much!!

Comment: @cmd,  Please provide that as an answer so that he can accept it and close this session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as cmd said above, is simply

```
labels = chans.strip().split()
```